# Highlighting a field in angularJS if different value is present after comparison

Tags: html, angularjs

I have rows of data and each row has 2 columns.

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2"><strong>Natural ID:</strong></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">{{ctrl.firstobject.naturalId}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-2"><strong>ManulaID:</strong></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">{{ctrl.firstobject.manualID}}</div>
 </div>
```

Now, I would like to compare the value of the field called "NaturalID" with another Natural ID (accessed by ctrl.CustomObject.naturalid) and if these two values are different, I would like to highlight in red the field corresponding to Natural ID in the above HTML. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-class` something like

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope, $timeout) {
$scope.firstobject={
naturalId:1,
manualID:2
}
$scope.customObj={
naturalId:2
}
});
```

```css
.red{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" >
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2"><strong>Natural ID:</strong>
   </div>
     <div class="col-md-4" ng-class="{'red':firstobject.naturalId !=customObj.naturalId}">{{firstobject.naturalId}}<span ng-if="firstobject.naturalId !=customObj.naturalId" class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></span>
     </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><strong>ManulaID:</strong>
        </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">{{firstobject.manualID}}</div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. Can you also tell me, what if instead of changing the color, I'd just want to add a glyphicon-alert in front of the field? How can that be done? It will be a great help.

Comment: you can use `ng-if` to show/hide alert see updated answer will not works here as glyphicon not included here also you can mark it as answer if this works for you